# Navigate between two scenes of different siblings in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux for navigation as I found that easy. I am stucked in a question about how I can navigate among two scene . Here is my case:

```
    <Scene key= "main_home" hideNavBar>
      <Scene initial  key="home" component={Home} title= "Home"  />
    </Scene>

    <Scene key="loginSignUp"  hideNavBar>
      <Scene initial  key="login" component={Login} hideNavBar= {false} title= "Login" />
      <Scene   key="signUp" component={SignUp} hideNavBar= {false} title= "SignUp"  />
    </Scene>
```

I want to navigate from home to login scene at one go. Any idea how I can achieve this?